# How to exclude files and directories to be zipped with ZipArchive or RecursiveDirectoryIterator?

Tags: php

how can I exclude directories or specific files to be added to my zip file, now it only works it the immediate parent of a file is inside the array of excluded_files but if there's more than one sublevel, those files get added and by default the parent directory (the one excluded) is created, so at the end, I have all of the folders including the ones I do not want.

```
    /** Lets say we have */
    $this->excluded_files = ['.git','migrations'];


    /** Recursive generation */
    $iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory);
    // skip dot files while iterating 
    $iterator->setFlags(RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);

    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

    foreach ($files as $file) {
      if (is_dir($file) && !in_array(pathinfo($file , PATHINFO_DIRNAME), $this->excluded_files)) {

        $file = str_replace($directory, '', $file);

        /** Adding folder to zip file */
        $this->zip->addEmptyDir($file);

      } elseif (is_file($file) && !in_array(basename($file), $this->excluded_files)) {

        /** Adding file to zip */
        $this->zip->addFromString(str_replace($directory, '', $file), file_get_contents($file));

      }
      /** anything else will we skipped */
    }

    return $this;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in her:

```
basename($file)
```

> basename — Returns trailing name component of path

This will return the file name instead of the parent directory in your second condition, You should deal with it as you did with directories as follows:-

```
pathinfo($file , PATHINFO_DIRNAME)
```

or you may make a use of the API of the internal Iterators which looks more clean as follows

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (
        in_array($file->getBasename(), $this->excluded_files) ||
        in_array(basename($file->getPath()), $this->excluded_files)
    ) {
        continue;
    }
    $tmpName = str_replace($directory, '', $file->getPathname());

    if ($file->isDir()) {
        $this->zip->addEmptyDir($tmpName);
    } else {
        $this->zip->addFromString($tmpName, file_get_contents($file));
    }
}
```

Note that we are checking against two conditions, to check if the current directory is in the excluded array and in case if the type is file check if the parent directory in the excluded array.

---

As an alternative, you may make a use of RegexIterator too.

```
$iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory);

$iterator->setFlags(RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);

$recursiveIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

$files = new RegexIterator($recursiveIterator, '#^((?!migration|\.git).)*$#');

foreach ($files as $file) {
    $tmpName = str_replace($directory, '', $file->getPathname());

    if ($file->isDir()) {
        $this->zip->addEmptyDir($tmpName);
    } else {
        $this->zip->addFromString($tmpName, file_get_contents($file));
    }
}

return $list;
```